# Activating overlay background when hovering over link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am preparing a layout for a blog and need to make a slideshow more or less as follows:

[image]

I'm already able to do a lot via CSS, but I have a problem! The images only activate when the mouse hovers over the `div`, but I need the image to be activated, or better, be colored, when hovering over the image link.

Could someone help me out with this?

Take my code via BOOTPLY

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/CyYjZEr33h)

I do not know if I do this via CSS or only via JavaScript. I even tried to do more via JavaScript but do not know much about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the pseudo-class `:hover` on the parent of the image and text.  This will change the opacity of the image when you hover over any child of that element.

Change this

```
.img-box-feature:hover{opacity:1;}
```

to this

```
[class*="box-"]:hover .img-box-feature{opacity:1;}
```

[See updated Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/wetssYeAAT)

Also, I suggest you change the classes from `box-um`, `box-dois`, and `box-tres` to just `box`.  Then you can use `.box:nth-child()` or `.box:nth-of-type()` to target a specific one.

Answer (score 1):

If you change this line:

```
.img-box-feature:hover {
  opacity:1;
}
```

to this:

```
.img-box-feature:hover,
.img-box-feature.hover{
  opacity:1;
}
```

you could use jQuery to toggle to new class:

```
$('.over-text-feature h1 a').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
  $(this).closest('[class^="col-"]').find('.img-box-feature').toggleClass('hover');
})
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/evtlBSG6Kz)

Answer (score 0):

try out the [webkit filters](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/say-hello-to-webkit-filters--net-23318)

e.g. .img-box-feature2:hover{-webkit-filter: invert(100%);}

You could also use contrast (%), brightness (decimal), blur (px), or sepia (%)

Answer (score 0):

It remains unclear to me if you want the images to active *also* when hovering over the text, or *only* when hovering over the text. I also wonder if you want *all* images to be active to just *one*.

In case you want *all* the images to *only* become active when hovering the text, you could move the text element to be the first child of `.section-slider`, and use the CSS sibling selector: `~`.

Like this:

```html
<section class="section-slider">
  <div class="over-text-feature">
    <h1><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos</a></h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6 box-um">
         <div class="img-box-feature" style="background-image:url('http://lounge.obviousmag.org/a_boleia_da_ideia/2012/08/gatimonias-ou-maldita-curiosidade.html.jpg?v=20150627141437')"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6 box-dois">
         <div class="img-box-feature2" style="background-image:url('http://lounge.obviousmag.org/a_boleia_da_ideia/2012/08/gatimonias-ou-maldita-curiosidade.html.jpg?v=20150627141437')"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6 box-tres">
         <div class="img-box-feature2" style="background-image:url('http://lounge.obviousmag.org/a_boleia_da_ideia/2012/08/gatimonias-ou-maldita-curiosidade.html.jpg?v=20150627141437')"></div>
       </div>
       <div style="clear: both;"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3">01</div>
       <div class="col-md-3">01</div>
       <div class="col-md-3">01</div>
       <div class="col-md-3">01</div>
     </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

```css
/* SLIDER PRINCIPAL */
.section-slider{ background:#000; width: 100%;}

.img-box-feature{
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 70% ; /* % of width, defines aspect ratio*/    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    opacity:0.3;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;

}
.img-box-feature2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 35% ; /* % of width, defines aspect ratio*/    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    opacity:0.3;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.over-text-feature{ z-index:100;
    position:absolute;    
    color:white;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    bottom: 15px;
    width: 95%;
    left:10px;
    border-left: 5px solid #fff;
    padding-left: 10px;
    }
.over-text-feature h1{ font-size: 1.8em;}
.over-text-feature h1 a{color: #00aeef;}
.section-slider .box-um{float: left; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important;}
.section-slider .box-dois{float: right;margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important;}
.section-slider .box-tres{float: right; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important;}
.over-text-feature:hover ~ .container .img-box-feature, .over-text-feature:hover ~ .container .img-box-feature2{opacity: 1;}
```